# Is this a bug relating to sub2ind / ind2sub?

Tags: matlab

I was trying to do sub2ind on single-precision variables that I came across the following strange behavior. For example, when I try:

```
[a b] = ind2sub([50000 50000], sub2ind([50000 50000], single(1000), single(1000)))
```

I get:

```
a = 1001
b = 1000
```

Is this a bug or I am missing something? I know this can be because of an overflow somewhere in matlab's code but it shouldn't happen, right?

I get the same wrong behavior from 64-bit (glnxa64) R2012a, R2011a, R2010b, R2010a, but correct results from 32-bit (glnx86) R2010b.

Comment: I get a=1000; b=1000.  (R2011A)

Comment: I get a = 1001;b= 1000 with release 2012a.

Comment: I get the same results as the OP with R2010b. The error appears to occur with the IND2SUB step, not the SUB2IND step.

Comment: The same results as what @gnovice ?

Comment: the problem is with both: it's a rounding problem given the scale of the numbers: compare `sub2ind([50000 50000], single(1000), single(1000))` with  `sub2ind([50000 50000], single(1001), single(1000))`

Comment: I get the same behavior for 64-bit (glnxa64) R2012a, R2011a, R2010b, R2010a, but correct results for 32-bit (glnx86) R2010b. (I will update the post too)

Comment: @Rasman: So it is. It should also be noted that a 50000-by-50000 matrix would take up multiple GB, so you would likely [not be able to allocate the matrix anyway](http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1100/1107.html).

Comment: @gnovice: How about a logical or sparse matrix!?

Comment: @user1210230: Even a logical matrix will still take 2.5 GB of storage. A sparse matrix should work size-wise, but you'd still have the above conversion issues if you use single-precision for your subscripted indices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason this happens is the following.

On line 35 of ind2sub.m is

```
vi = rem(ndx-1, k(i)) + 1;
```

where ndx is the index that is passed in. Thus ndx is 49951000 via the call from sub2ind. Now, when you pass in a single precision value, it forces matlab to evaluate all math in single precision. Thus, compare the difference in what happens on l.35.

```
K>> 49951000-1
ans =
        49950999

K>> single(49951000)-1
ans =
        49951000
```

This subtraction of a small number from a large number is the issue. So no, this isn't a bug, it's a limitation to the precision of single-precision floating point. [This might help some.](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/floating_point/understanding_floating_point_representation.html)

edit: As pointed out by Rasman, a nice way of showing this is with [eps](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/eps.html)

```
eps(single(49951000))=4
```

so any value added or subtracted from single(49951000) that is on the range (-4,4) will result in 495100 being returned due to the accuracy of single-precision.

Comment: I disagree: This should be considered a bug because as long as the input and output of a function fits in single-precision the function should behave correctly. By overflow I meant the same limitation of single-precision in my original post, although not an accurate choice of word.

Comment: No, not at all. You are asking Matlab to perform a calculation with single precision numbers (by passing in a single). You cannot mix single precision and double precision without a cast. Just because the *output* fits within [realmin('single'), realmax('single)] has nothing to do with if the numbers you are computing make sense given the limitations of the FP format you choose.

Answer (score 1):

Been thinking some more, especially looking a gnovice's comment which sparked everything.

so here's the thing: a single is a 32-bit signed floating point number. Thus, there is a limitation onto how precise you can get your data

`eps(single(49951000)) = 4`, while `eps(single(50000^2)) = 256`

Thus your range is off, and you will get quantization especially as you increase the values of the indices:

```
for i = 1000:1010
    sub2ind([50000 50000], single(i), single(1000))
end
```

If you really want a 32 bit number, I suggest you use uint32, as you will be able to represent all data points (a square matrix of order 50000 has 2.5e+09 data points > 2^32 (=4.3e9)) .

```
for i = 1000:1010
    sub2ind([50000 50000], uint32(i), uint32(1000))
end
```

Comment: Single is a floating point number (see http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/floating-point-numbers.html#f2-108458) not an integer. realmax('single') ans = 3.4028e+38.

Comment: fair point, but the problem isn't any different: `eps(single(50000^2)) = 256` and eps(single(49951000) = 4)

Comment: well yes, that's the problem here (as per my answer). Single just falls apart with these types of numbers, especially when you start subtracting small ones because, as you say, eps(single(49951000) = 4. So with a value that large +- anything <4 results in a loss of precision. I'll amend my answer with that -- it's a nice way of showing this.

Comment: @Chris: However, `sub2ind` can't deal with fractional numbers, anyway, so it makes sense to use an integer type.

Comment: @Jonas, of course. But that has nothing to do with the OP's problem. Using a single precision float in this case is clearly asking for trouble.